# Programs not responding windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have installed Windows 10 via the free install that was offered last year.

I had no issues and everything worked until around April this year after an update.

I start the computer, log in and everything works for a while and then for some reason I can not open the Start menu with either mouse or keyboard. I can open Word which is in my task bar, I can open a doc but cannot do anything else in Word. Cortana wont open etc. I have Chrome on the task bar which still is active.

I can right click on Start and click restart and then I'm back to it working,  everything is fine until it freezes again. The tech guy reckoned it was my mouse (it wasn't), then some programs which he got rid of (it wasn't) so $110 dollars later I'm still looking for help.

I cant access the programs using touch screen either.

Is there any way to either fix this and find out what it causing it?

Comment: This is usually the result of a slow PC. How much RAM does your PC have? Do you have a HDD or an SDD? Finally, go to Task Manager (if you can) and check your Memory usage - are certain programs utilizing all of the system resources?

Comment: Im sorry you are going to have to explain your terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is an error in Windows 10. First, boot up elevated `cmd` and run

```
C:\%WinDir%\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management Tool
Version: 10.X.XXXXX.XXX

Image Version: 10.X.XXXXX.XXX

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\%WinDir%\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan. This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

C:\%WinDir%\system32>
```

Restart your computer. Check if the problem persists.

If `sfc` says that it `found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.`  you will have to repair the corrupted files manually. For more details head to

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reinstall it ,its a bug

either way you need to reinstall it , if you'll go any service center they will ask you the same , because you deleted some  `.dll` files ,now if you have backup then its good , or uplug the battery start it in safe mode and then go to recovery check for your last restore point ( prefer if it points to time when you installed it )

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem for windows 10. i face this same problem start menu issue about 2 times. search a lot and found many solution which fixed for others  but not work for me any solution.
after i create a new user and delete old user it's working fine on new user profile. i moved user data to new user profile. **before delete user copy it's data if you need any.**

I suggest first try following step by step solution if not work then you need to **create new user**
 [First try Here](http://mspoweruser.com/solution-start-menu-not-working-windows-10/)
 [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana)

Note: **If you need profile data copy others drive user data**
**DO NOT NEED TO REINSTALL**